# How to get packet info at Border Router Node?

Tags: c, contiki, iot

I have made udp-server and udp-client communication via border router node. It able to communicate from client to server.

I have difficulty in how to get packet info like ... source IP, Destination IP at border router node?? I am able to get it at server node but how to get same thing in border router node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When recieved by a router, a packet is routed by the function `tcpip_ipv6_output`, into file [`tcpip.c`](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/net/ip/tcpip.c). You can activate PRINTFs of this file by setting the `DEBUG` macro to `DEBUG_PRINT`.

In this function, you can get the source & destination addresses with `UIP_IP_BUF->destipaddr` and `UIP_IP_BUF->srcipaddr`. Check, for example, when the route to the destination is looked up in the routing table :

```
uip_ds6_route_t *route;
/* Check if we have a route to the destination address. */
route = uip_ds6_route_lookup(&UIP_IP_BUF->destipaddr);
```

Comment: thanks for helping. Is there any way to send or request data (temp) from linux to connect it with border router or using scapy like tools send packet..

Comment: If i want to drop packet at router then what to do .. i have created one black list ip addr

Comment: @sagar: I see two solution to be able to blacklist a IP. Either remove its address from routing table (see `uip_ds6_route_rm`), this can be problematic if the IP address match a big prefix into your routing table. Or modify the source code of the `tcpip_ipv6_output` function by checking into it if the destination IP address is on the black list, and if so, simply `return` from this function.

Comment: Thanks @ryolait you save my day.. Now last problem is after SLIP connection to border-router how can I send TCP, UDP or ICMP request from linux host machine which send packets from different address.. so my task is generate scenario of requesting node from 100 different sources. I tried scapy tool but not able to connect interface to "tun0" it shows error for tun0. Any other way to generate such traffic ?? Thanks in advance

Comment: @sagar: I've heard a little about scapy, but not enough to help you on this point. If you try only to get packets generated from a linux computer, I think you should ask another question on stackoverflow, with more corresponding tags. You will get better advices than mine.